# XML jquery parse help

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, parsing

I have a weird XML file that I'm trying to parse.

```
<Data>
<Row>
<Field name = "whatever" pos ="1">STUFF</Field>
<Field name = "whatever2" pos ="2">MORE STUFF</Field>
<Field name = "whatever3" pos ="3">EVEN MORE STUFF</Field>
</Row>
<Row>
<Field name = "whatever" pos ="1">Different STUFF</Field>
<Field name = "whatever2" pos ="2">MORE Different STUFF</Field>
<Field name = "whatever3" pos ="3">EVEN MORE Different STUFF</Field>
</Row>
</Data>
```

I tried getting the data by using "Row" which works but how do I call the individual field names? In firebug they all look like "Field". I tried:

```
myvalue : $("whatever", this).text()
```

But that doesn't grab it.

Thanks

---

Code from a comment below:

```
function callAjax(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xmlResponse) {
            $.merge(data1, $("ROW", xmlResponse).map(returnResults).get());
        } // end of success }); }
```

---

```
function returnResults() {
    formatedURL = $('Field[name="EL_VALUES_FIELD2"]', this).text();
    return {
        value: $('Field[name="EL_VALUES_FIELD1"]', this).text(),
        label: $('Field[name="EL_VALUES_FIELD1"]', this).text() + " " + $("EL_VALUES_FIELD4", this).text(),
        title: $('Field[name="EL_VALUES_FIELD1"]', this).text(),
        url: formatedURL,
        description: $('Field[name="EL_VALUES_FIELD3"]', this).text(),
        keywords: $('Field[name="EL_VALUES_FIELD4"]', this).text()
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the [attribute equals selector `[attrname="value"]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector).  For instance:

```
$('Row', this).eq(0).find('Field[name="whatever2"]').text()
```

This finds the `Field` element whose name is `whatever2` within the first (index `0`) `Row` element.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without that index? I'm compiling all of this into objects for an autocomplete search bar. I'm working with this:

Comment: @Specked How do you know which `Row` element you want to get?

Comment: How can I apply that to my need? http://pastebin.com/CrGgeW1K  I'm using this as a datasource for autocomplete so I need it to iterate through all of the Row elements

Comment: @Specked I've added those lines of code to your question. In future, please edit your question if you need to add more detail.

Answer (score 0):

try `$(Field [name=whatever])`